# Expression Engine PHP Error Log

Tags: php, error, php-errors

How can i find or get an PHP Error Log? Not server-side, only on Expression Engine Level.

On my server i can see an error log but to fix a problem with assets, i need a EE-side php error log.

Answer (score 1):

EE logs errors to the PHP error log. But, you can see errors in EE's responses (i.e., on your web pages) by setting in your config.php:

```
$config['debug'] = '1'; // display errors only to the Super Admin
```

or

```
$config['debug'] = '2'; // display errors to everyone
```